# Is it possible to store values of dgrid store in some variable or print in console

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, dgrid

I m using dgrid store to show the grid (dgrid 0.4). Here is my code

```
require([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dojo/Deferred',
    'dstore/RequestMemory',
    'dstore/QueryResults',
    'dstore/Trackable',
    'dgrid/Grid',
    'dgrid/Selection',
    'dgrid/extensions/Pagination',
    'dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry',
    'dgrid/extensions/DnD',
    'dgrid/Keyboard',
    'dgrid/Editor',
    'dgrid/extensions/ColumnHider',
    'dgrid/extensions/ColumnResizer',
    'dgrid/Selector',
    'dojo/_base/array'
      ], function (declare, Deferred, RequestMemory, QueryResults, Trackable, Grid, Selection, Pagination, DijitRegistry, DnD, Keyboard, Editor, ColumnHider, ColumnResizer, Selector, array) {

    var grid = new (declare([Grid, Trackable, Selection, Pagination, DijitRegistry, DnD, Keyboard, Editor, ColumnHider, ColumnResizer]))({
            collection: store,
      //    items: store.items,
      //    query: {PRID: '*'},
            columns: getColumns(),
      //    className: 'dgrid-autoheight',
            pagingLinks: 1,
            rowsPerPage: 10,
            pagingTextBox: true,
            firstLastArrows: true,
            pageSizeOptions: [10, 15, 20,25],
            loadingMessage: 'Loading data...',
            noDataMessage: 'No results found.',
        }, 'grid');
        //grid.renderArray(data);
        alert(store);
        grid.startup();
        alert(store);
        });
```

I want to know whether it is possible to store the value of grid in some variable or is there any way to show the entire grid in console or print in console.log.
I tried to alert the store but it shows object. Is there any way to get that object and store it in the array of object?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just asking how to read all of the items from the store, the simplest way would be something like this:

```
store.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Note that this implicitly fetches all items from the store, which is fine for in-memory stores (since they already have all of their data loaded before you ever fetch regardless), but you probably wouldn't want to do it with e.g. `Request` or `Rest` with a large data set.

If you're interested in accessing only the items that are currently rendered in the grid, there's not really a specific way in mind to do it, but you could do something like this (where `query` is `dojo/query`):

```
var rows = query('.dgrid-row', grid.contentNode);
var length = rows.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    console.log(grid.row(rows[i]).data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with the stores you're using but going off what Ken said, you could use `console.table(data)` to avoid looping and to get a nicer format. Some stores you can do something like `console.table(store.query());`.